# 403 (Forbidden) error when submitting a form from a Word Pess site

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, form-submit

On [THIS](http://testing.merchantlaw.com/class-actions/propecia-proscar-class-action) page, I have an instance of a form created with Contact Form 7 Word Press Plugin> the plugin works on almost all the pages, except for this which contains the word 'Propecia' in the Subject field. If I put the same word - 'Propecia' - n any other form, that form does not work.

Same issue with [another page](http://testing.merchantlaw.com/class-actions/premarin-premplus-class-action).

Can anyone please give me a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: you're form is stuck, you need to configure your form. i filled it in with test all over and it doesn't take you anywhere. spend more time on the configuring the plugin. make sure it processes the data first.

Comment: On [THIS](http://testing.merchantlaw.com/class-actions/indian-metis-scoop-class-action) page there is **the same** form, and it works. The same for the majority of pages listed [HERE](http://testing.merchantlaw.com/class-actions).